# Eclipse not recognizing Android supplied drawable?

Tags: android, eclipse, drawable

In my app, I've got a menu which pops up when the user hits the "Menu" physical button. It's going mighty-fine except for the fact that Eclipse isn't recognizing one of the drawables that is built into the Android.jar package. If you look and see, "ic_menu_refresh" is built into the supplied Android.jar when you create an Android Project.
I'm using the following code to use the particular icon:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
```

Eclipse gives me an error stating the following:

```
error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh').   
menu.xml    
/Yeousch/res/layout line 3  
Android AAPT Problem
```

I can clearly see the resource but Eclipse seems to ignore it. Any solutions?

Comment: Did you clean the project and try?

Comment: I had the same problem. It appears that you aren't allowed to use some of the built-in graphics for some weird reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile error is informing you the resource you want is not public, not for applications to use.
According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html#examples9 applications should provide their own copies of these drawable resources.